# Getting an error at async remove(item) after upgrading to Angular 9

Tags: npm, chokidar

I am getting an error while `npm install` don't know how to fix this. Please help.

```
node --version
v10.16.3

[ERROR] C:\Development\Angular9Upgrade\chp\frontend\src\main\frontend\node_modules\chokidar\index.js:151
[ERROR]   async remove(item) {
[ERROR]         ^^^^^^
[ERROR] SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
[ERROR]     at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
[ERROR]     at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
[ERROR]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
[ERROR]     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
[ERROR]     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
[ERROR]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
[ERROR]     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
[ERROR]     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```